# SceneKit/ARKit - Rendering a depth map of scene?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, metal

I have a scene containing SCNNode models, and a camera.

I'd like to generate a depth map render of my scene (from perspective of camera) - something like this: [image]

How can this be achieved? Currently looking into SCNTechnique but haven't found many resources.

Comment: Just brainstorming. What about a SCNProgram, that includes a metal shader. It can incorporate with Scenekit and you can file any information to it, like i.Ex depthBuffer information (or distances). The idea is great. Good question

Comment: Try using SCNRenderer, see here in this article how to use it for the camera scene you need: https://qiita.com/akira108/items/a743138fca532ee193fe

More about pointOfView here:https://magicien.github.io/JSceneKit/class/js/SceneKit/SCNRenderer.js~SCNRenderer.html#instance-set-pointOfView

Answer (score 2):

This here might not be the Final Solution, but it could give you a guidance, how to achieve a Depth rendering technique.

Note: Everything here is currently dependant on the camera Distance to the Geometry. Very simplified implementation. It uses a `SCNProgram()` for the Material.

Here comes the `GameViewController.swift` :

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView            : SCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene()
        
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.camera?.automaticallyAdjustsZRange = true
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        
        // place the camera
        // cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 100)
        
        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
        
        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
        
        // set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
        
        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        
        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        
        // configure the view
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        
        sceneView.scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents   = UIColor.black
        sceneView.scene?.background.contents            = UIColor.black
        
        // self.setupCube()
        self.setupRing()
        self.setupStick()
    }
    
    
    func setupCube() {
        let cube = SCNBox(width: 20.0, height: 20.0, length: 20.0, chamferRadius: 2.5)
        let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: cube)
        cubeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial =  depthMaterial() // chromeMaterialMetal()
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
    }
    
    func setupRing() {
        let ring = SCNTorus(ringRadius: 20.0, pipeRadius: 4.0)
        let ringNode = SCNNode(geometry: ring)
        ringNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, +10.0, 20.0)
        ringNode.geometry?.firstMaterial =  depthMaterial() // chromeMaterialMetal()
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(ringNode)
        
        let ring2 = SCNTorus(ringRadius: 20.0, pipeRadius: 4.0)
        let ringNode2 = SCNNode(geometry: ring2)
        ringNode2.position = SCNVector3(0.0, -10.0, 20.0)
        ringNode2.geometry?.firstMaterial =  depthMaterial() // chromeMaterialMetal()
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(ringNode2)
    }
    
    func setupStick() {
        let stick = SCNCylinder(radius: 5.0, height: 70.0)
        let stickNode = SCNNode(geometry: stick)
        stickNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, 20.0)
        stickNode.geometry?.firstMaterial =  depthMaterial() // chromeMaterialMetal()
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(stickNode)
    }
    
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }
    
    func depthMaterial() -> SCNMaterial {
        
        // let depthValue: Float = 100.0 // Adjust this value based on your scene's depth range
        
        let sceneProgramDepth = SCNProgram()
        sceneProgramDepth.vertexFunctionName    = "myVertexDepth"
        sceneProgramDepth.fragmentFunctionName  = "myFragmentDepth"
        // sceneProgramDepth.setValue(depthValue, forKey: "maxDepth") // to be implemented, ToDo
        
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.name                           = "metal"
        material.program = sceneProgramDepth // doing this will replace the entire built-in SceneKit shaders for that object.
        
        return material
    }
    
}
```

And this here is the Depth-Shader (and some Variations of it) `shaders.metal`:

```
// Default Metal Header for SCNProgram
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

// Nodebuffer (you only need the enabled Matrix floats)
struct MyNodeBuffer {
    float4x4 modelViewTransform; // required
    float4x4 normalTransform; // required
    // float4x4 inverseModelViewTransform;
    // float4x4 modelTransform;
    // float4x4 inverseModelTransform;
    // float4x4 modelViewProjectionTransform;
    // float4x4 inverseModelViewProjectionTransform;
};

// Input Struct
typedef struct {
    float3 position [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
} MyDepthInput;

// Struct filled by the Vertex Shader
struct SimpleVertexDepth {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float depth; // Store depth information
};

// Declare the maximum depth variable // needs to be filed by Scenekit, ToDo
// constant float maxDepth [[function_constant(0)]];

// Simple Vertex Shader
vertex SimpleVertexDepth myVertexDepth(MyDepthInput in [[stage_in]],
                                       constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                                       constant MyNodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]])
{
    float4 modelSpacePosition(in.position, 1.0f);
    float4 eyeSpacePosition = scn_node.modelViewTransform * modelSpacePosition;

    // Calculate depth from the vertex position in eye space
    float depth = length(eyeSpacePosition.xyz);

    SimpleVertexDepth out;
    out.position = scn_frame.projectionTransform * eyeSpacePosition;
    out.depth = depth;
    return out;
}

// Simple Depth
// fragment half4 myFragmentDepth(SimpleVertexDepth in [[stage_in]])
// {
//     // Map depth to grayscale color inversely
//     float gray = 1.0 - saturate(in.depth / 100); // Invert depth mapping
//     return half4(gray, gray, gray, 1.0);
// }

// Another Variation (Better)
fragment half4 myFragmentDepth(SimpleVertexDepth in [[stage_in]])
{
    // Define a contrast factor to control the contrast
    float contrastFactor = 3.0; // Adjust this value to control contrast
    
    // Map depth to grayscale color with increased contrast
    float gray = 1.0 - pow(saturate(in.depth / 100), contrastFactor);
    
    return half4(gray, gray, gray, 1.0);
}

// Far away is brighter
// fragment half4 myFragmentDepth(SimpleVertexDepth in [[stage_in]])
// {
//     // Map depth to grayscale color
//     float gray = in.depth / 100; // maxDepth; // You can set maxDepth based on your scene
//     return half4(gray, gray, gray, 1.0);
// }

// Better Variation
// fragment half4 myFragmentDepth(SimpleVertexDepth in [[stage_in]])
// {
//     // Define a contrast factor to control the contrast level
//     float contrastFactor = 3.0; // Adjust this value to control contrast
//
//     // Map depth to grayscale color with increased contrast
//     float gray = pow(in.depth / 100, contrastFactor); // maxDepth is the maximum depth value in your scene
//     return half4(gray, gray, gray, 1.0);
// }
```

My preferred one (for the moment) goes by the name "Another Variation (Better)" The Result looks like so:

[image: SceneKit Depth Render Shader]

Feel free to experiment with that stuff. I hope I could help in some way. *(If you find any better solution, I would be very interested in seeing it.)*

PS: as a scratch-project use the SceneKit Default Template with the Space-Ship and delete the Space-Ship :)

Comment: would the render here be affected by the lighting in the scene? I was hoping there would be a way without relying on lighting. Basically just rendering a depth map based on how far each point is from the camera.

Comment: no, lighting is not involved in this techique. it's all based on didtance to the camera.

Comment: tnx Zay, I'll give this a shot tomorrow!

Comment: regarding your question about involvation of ighting: the Lights, that are added by the GameViewController are just the default lights from the Apple-Template. You can ignore or delete them.

Comment: tnx a lot for the bounty!

Comment: @ZAY, is the depth map here accurate? Ex, if you converted to a point cloud, would it actually represent the geometry?

Comment: As I mentioned in this Answer, the depts is currently dependant on the camera distance to the object, with the most far away distance as a definition. (what would result usually in total black.) Everything behind this distand remains in darkness. The Point for total white, the shortest dept, is close to the camera. This is all I have for the moment. If you want to have depts for each object from black to white, you will need to incorporate the geometry distance within the shader. I never followed this strategy for that example.