# SceneKit - extra t geometry depth into an image

Tags: scenekit, metal

My goal is to extract and render a SceneKit geometry depth into an image.

This is my code:

```
func renderDepthMap(using scene: SCNScene, size: CGSize) -> NSImage? {
    guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
          let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue(),
          let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else {
        return nil
    }

    let renderer = SCNRenderer(device: device, options: nil)
    renderer.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    renderer.scene = scene

    // Setup MTLTexture for depth data
    let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .depth32Float, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height), mipmapped: false)
    textureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead]
    guard let depthTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor) else {
        return nil
    }

    let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.texture = depthTexture
    renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.loadAction = .clear
    renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.storeAction = .store
    renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1.0

    renderer.render(atTime: 0, viewport: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size), commandBuffer: commandBuffer, passDescriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
    commandBuffer.commit()

    // Convert depthTexture to UIImage
    return convertToUIImage(depthTexture: depthTexture)
}

// Function to convert MTLTexture to UIImage
func convertToUIImage(depthTexture: MTLTexture) -> NSImage? {
    let width = depthTexture.width
    let height = depthTexture.height
    let pixelByteCount = 4 * width * height

    // Allocate buffer for pixel data
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    guard let pixelData = malloc(pixelByteCount) else { return nil }

    // Get pixel data
    depthTexture.getBytes(pixelData, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height), mipmapLevel: 0)

    // Create CGImage from pixel data
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
    guard let context = CGContext(data: pixelData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue),
          let cgImage = context.makeImage() else {
        free(pixelData)
        return nil
    }

    // Create NSImage from CGImage
    let imageSize = NSSize(width: width, height: height)
    let image = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: imageSize)
    
    renderedDepthImage = image

    // Free the allocated pixel data
    free(pixelData)

    return image
}
```

However the render image is all black, so I am probably doing something wrong here...

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What have you done for troubleshooting? Have you verified the MTLTexture is right? Have you verified that your guards aren't returning nil? I'd place a print statement in each guard before exiting. If you make a minimal reproducible project I'll take a look.

Comment: Probably this answer can give you some guidance with depth stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122196/scenekit-arkit-rendering-a-depth-map-of-scene/77136509#77136509